# Slicer background by value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I wanna highlight the background of a slicer when more then 10 items are selected.
My measure:

`ColorBackground = IF(COUNTX(ALLSELECTED(Table), Table[Column])<=10, "Green", "Red")`

So I use conditional formatting by field value.
When I use the conditional of an table column or as background for a textbox or shape it works as expected.
But when I use the same for the background of a slicer the background the background is always red.
Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Warm regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work on a slicer. There are posts on powerbi.com asking for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.
As workaround I placed a shape under the slicer where conditional formatting works.